# Script not assigning WMI objects to array correctly

Tags: powershell, wmi

I am trying to create a script that detects domain user profiles that are up to 15 days old and removes them. This will be bundled in a job that will log out any idle sessions before it runs.

I am aware that this would normally be done via GPO, however it is not fit for purpose for this particular business area for various reasons.

Here is my code:

```bsh
#Assign how old the user profile must be for deletion
[int]$NoOfDays = 15

#Get WMI object where it is a domain account and over 15 days old
$Objects = @(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserProfile | Where {
    (!$_.Special) -and
    $_.ConvertToDateTime($_.LastUseTime) -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-15)
})

if ($Objects -eq $null) {
    #If no users returned, write to host.
    Write-Host "no profiles found for deletion"
} else {
    #If users are found, do the following
    foreach ($Object in $Objects) {
        Write-Host "'$($object.LocalPath)' has been identified for deletion"
    }

    foreach ($Object in $Objects) {
        try {
            Write-Host "Attempting to delete profile '$($Object.LocalPath)'"
            Remove-WmiObject
            Write-Host "Deleted profile '$($Object.LocalPath)' successfully."
        } catch {
            Write-Host "Unable to delete profile '$($Object.LocalPath)'" -ErrorAction Continue
        }
    }
}
```

There is no output, it just returns to command line with no error straight away.

I have attempted commenting out the bit that removes the profile, ending the else after the first for each statement to see what is identified for deletion however it has not worked.

Comment: it's seemed that a some input arguments for the Remove-WmiObject cmdlet are missed  in the given above code.

Comment: @Andrei Odegov yeah sorry thanks for pointing that out. I have managed to get the deletion working correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$Objects = @(...)` ensures that `$Objects` is an array, even if the command doesn't return a result. An array (even an empty array) never equals `$null`, so your first condition is never triggered.

Change

```
if ($Objects -eq $null) {
```

to

```
if ($Objects.Count -gt 0) {
```

and the code should do what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to [Ansgar's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45161933/5039142) you could avoid assigning the `$Objects` variable to an array (can't see why this is required).

```
$Objects = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserProfile | Where {
    (!$_.Special) -and
    $_.ConvertToDateTime($_.LastUseTime) -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-15)
}
```

`-eq $null` check can then be used. You may also find `[string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Object)` useful as this will detect an empty array.

You mention there is no output... that's suspect as you should get the `Write-Hosts` printing *something*. On my machine I got an error with `$_.ConvertToDateTime`... I recommend running your code a line at a tie in the console to make sure it's doing what you expect.

Comment: cannot get the datetime issue resolved with WMI for this code, there was an issue with my local copy of the script.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it turns out that it was a combination of issues. The main one is the PS version it runs on, does not work on 4. The next stage is to try and force PowerShell to run it as version 3. As previously stated it does not need to be handled within an array. Here is my final script (does not like returns after each and condition so left the formatting as is):

```
if ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -eq 4)
{
    Write-host "this script will terminate as machine is running PowerShell version 4"
    exit 1
    }

    Else
    {


Start-Sleep -s 5

Set-Location -Path C:\Users     

#Assign how old the user profile must be for deletion

        [DateTime]$AdjustedDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-15)  
        [DateTime]$CompareDate = Get-Date $AdjustedDate -Format MM-dd-yyyy
        $Hostname = $env:computername
        #$testdate = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserProfile | select {$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.lastusetime).ToShortDateString()}
        #write-host $testdate
        #Get WMI object where it is a domain account and over 15 days old
        $Objects = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserProfile | Where {(!$_.Special) -and ($_.ConvertToDateTime($_.lastusetime) -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-15))  -and $_.LocalPath -notlike "*.NET*" -and $_.LocalPath -notlike "*SQL*" -and  $_.LocalPath -notlike "*Admin*" -and $_.LocalPath -notlike "*ADMIN*"}


        #If no users returned, write to host.
        If($Objects.Count -eq 0)
        {
            Write-host "no profiles found for deletion"
        }

        #If users are found, do the following
        Else
        {
            Foreach($Object in $Objects)
            {
            Write-host "'$($object.LocalPath)' has been identified for deletion"
Write-host " "
            }

            Foreach($Object in $Objects)
            {

                            Try{
                            Write-Host "Attempting to delete profile '$($Object.LocalPath)'"
                            $UserSID = (Get-WmiObject Win32_UserProfile | Where {$_.LocalPath -like '$($object.LocalPath)'}).SID
                            Remove-WmiObject -InputObject $Object
                            Write-Host "Deleted profile '$($Object.LocalPath)' successfully."
                            }
                            Catch{
                            Write-Host "Unable to delete profile '$($Object.LocalPath)' due to the following error" 
                            Write-Host "$error" -ErrorAction Continue
                            }

            }       
        }
}
```